# Syntax for identity-insert FROM with no columns to insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have defined the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T_Comments_Paths
(
     path_id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Comments_Paths] PRIMARY KEY(path_id)
);


CREATE TABLE dbo.T_Comments 
(
     COM_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
    ,COM_Text NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(255) NULL 
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Comments] PRIMARY KEY(COM_Id)
);
```

If I need to get a path-id for a comment, for a single-value, I can get it like this:

```
DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (path_id bigint); 
INSERT INTO T_Comments_Paths OUTPUT INSERTED.path_id INTO @outputTable DEFAULT VALUES; 
SET @__pathuid = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @outputTable);
```

However, I fail to find the syntax for getting the inserted ids (multiple) for an insert from another table.

e.g. I want to do this:

```
DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (path_id bigint, com_id bigint); 
INSERT INTO T_Comments_Paths
OUTPUT INSERTED.path_id, com_id INTO @outputTable DEFAULT VALUES  
FROM T_Comments
```

this yields

> "Incorrect syntax near FROM-keyword"

How can I do that (without cursor) ? 
**Note:** I need to be compatible with MySQL, so I can't use newid(), because there's no uuid-type in MySQL, and I don't want to use varchar or varbinary either...

Comment: @Ivan Starostin: That's not a duplicate, he's inserting only one value. Found this post as well. That's not what I want.

Comment: Did you try prefixing com_id with INSERTED ? So: OUTPUT INSERTED.path_id, INSERTED.com_id INTO @outputTable DEFAULT VALUES ?

Comment: @John Joseph: I'm not inserting com_id into T_Comments_Paths, I'm just including it in the output table, together with the generated autoid.

Comment: You can't use `DEFAULT VALUES` with a `FROM` clause to insert multiple rows like this. You haven't shown how the link between comments and paths is persisted. Does it matter which `path_id` is linked to a given `com_id`? Could you add a `com_id` column to `T_Comments_Paths`?

Comment: @Ed Harper: Yes I could, but I don't want to. See, it's not necessary, I just need a unique id for every comment path (there can be multiple parents for one "comment"). I really don't need anything more than a generated unique id that i can use in a tripple column primary key. (path_id, ancestor, descendant, depth)

Comment: Would image MySQL compatibility rules out using a [seqence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx).  Probably the simplist method is to add an extra column to T_Comments_Path.  That would allow you to `INSERT INTO (NewColumn) SELECT 1 AS AlwaysTheSame OUTPUT ...`;.  But you'd have to pay the penalty of storing and documenting data you don't really need.  Which feels like a dirty hack.  AFAIK there is no multi-row default-only insert option.

Comment: @StefanSteiger - AFAIK no other choices are available to you; you must either generate `path_id` values one at a time, or accept the additional cost of an extra column on `T_Comments_Path`.

Comment: @Ed Harper: Yes, you're probably right. I'll probably save com_id anyway, because then I can set a foreign-key and with that ensure all associated paths are always deleted when a comment is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your problem boils down to this:
Adding n new rows to a identity column and then bring those newly added values to update an empty column in a table with n rows (@outputTable) without worrying about matching.

Setting up for testing

```
CREATE TABLE #T_Comments_Paths (
    path_id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK1] PRIMARY KEY (path_id)
);

CREATE TABLE #T_Comments (
    com_id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , com_text NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK2] PRIMARY KEY (com_id)
);

INSERT INTO #T_comments (com_text)
VALUES
('com1')
, ('com2');
```

**SOLUTION 1 **

If you are willing to add an extra column to the @outputTable (aka rowNo), you can get a shorter solution like this:

```
--Add a few values to make #T_Comment_Paths not empty, for testing purpose, making things not matching
INSERT INTO #T_Comments_Paths DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO #T_Comments_Paths DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO #T_Comments_Paths DEFAULT VALUES;

DECLARE @currentID BIGINT;
SELECT @currentID = IDENT_CURRENT('#T_Comments_Paths');
-- @currentID should be 3

DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (path_id bigint, com_id bigint, rowNo bigInt); 

INSERT INTO @outputTable (com_id, rowNo)
SELECT
    com_id
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM
    #T_comments;

MERGE #T_Comments_Paths tgt
USING @outputTable src
ON tgt.path_id = src.path_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT DEFAULT VALUES;

MERGE @outputTable tgt
USING (
    SELECT
        path_id
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo
    FROM
        #T_Comments_Paths
    WHERE
        path_id > @currentID
) src
ON tgt.RowNo = src.RowNo
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    tgt.path_id = src.PATH_ID;

SELECT *
FROM
    @outputTable;

SELECT *
FROM
    #T_Comments_Paths

DROP TABLE #T_Comments;
DROP TABLE #T_Comments_Paths;
```

**SOLUTION 2 **

If you insist on only have 2 columns in the @outputTable, then this is a solution (longer)

```
--Add a few values to make #T_Comment_Paths not empty, for testing purpose
INSERT INTO #T_Comments_Paths DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO #T_Comments_Paths DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO #T_Comments_Paths DEFAULT VALUES;
DECLARE @currentID BIGINT;
SELECT @currentID = IDENT_CURRENT('#T_Comments_Paths');
-- @currentID should be 3

DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (path_id bigint, com_id bigint); 
DECLARE @outputMiddleTable TABLE (rowNo bigint, com_id bigint);


INSERT INTO @outputTable (com_id)
SELECT
    com_id
FROM
    #T_comments;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        com_id
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo
    FROM
        @outputTable
)
INSERT INTO @outputMiddleTable (rowNo,com_id)
SELECT RowNo, com_id
FROM cte;

MERGE #T_Comments_Paths tgt
USING @outputTable src
ON tgt.path_id = src.path_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT DEFAULT VALUES;

WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT
    path_id
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo
FROM
    #T_Comments_Paths
WHERE
    path_id > @currentID
), cte2 AS (
SELECT
    cte1.path_id
    , t1.com_id
FROM
    @outputMiddleTable t1
    JOIN cte1 ON t1.rowNo = cte1.RowNo
)
UPDATE ot
SET path_id = cte2.path_id
FROM @outputTable ot
    JOIN cte2 ON ot.com_id = cte2.com_id

SELECT *
FROM
    @outputTable;


DROP TABLE #T_Comments;
DROP TABLE #T_Comments_Paths;
```

Comment: In case it hasn't been clear: I insist on 0 additional columns, and the two output columns, strictly. With an additional column, it's far shorter than any of your solutions, which all add an additional column. Also merge isn't necessary nor desired. It's just a bug source for a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: I meant an extra column to the variable table outputTable, not the original T_Comments_Paths table (which in my solutions, it is #T_Comments_Paths). I put in two solutions, one with an extra column in the variable outputTable, the other with no additional column in variable outputTable (but it need an extra table variable)

Comment: I don't think anyone reading this will understand what's going on. For that reason alone, it can't be called a "solution". Also, I don't see what benefits this offers over a cursor. It's longer and more complicated. I'm trying to write portable, RDBMS-independent code, thus want as few of things like this as technically possible. Went with an additional column, as that's the only solution that prevents things like cursors or this. The correct answer to the question is thus: "it's not possible".